# Test unity game in iOS without iDevice

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I already search so much in the web and nothing, so I've this question:

There's any way to test or run a unity game that I'm developing for ios in a emulator for pc (windows).

I haven't any iDevice like iPod, iPad, iPhone, Mac...

Really thanks!!!

Comment: There is not a way to my knowledge to run an iOS simulator on a Windows OS native (You could look at running a VM of macOS). Two options I recommend is A) find a friend who has a device you can borrow, or B) look at buying a mac mini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done and below are the steps to follow:

**1**.Download VMware Workstation 12 Player (Non commercial use)

**2**.Download and install OS X 10.11

**3**.Install Xcode after opening the VMware Workstation.

That's really it. You can use the simulator for Xcode to run your built Unity game. Remember that this is only for testing your game during development phase. Do not release your game if it has not been tested on the physical iOS device.

See [this](https://www.tactig.com/install-macos-sierra-on-vmware/) and [this](https://www.tactig.com/use-iphone-7-ios-10-vmware/) post for thorough instructions.